# Checkbox returns false when checked instead of true - Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, devise

So I am trying to build an e-commerce website for a school project with Ruby on Rails, using Devise for the users.
I am still learning this language on my own, and i encoutered a problem.

I've got this view generated by devise in : **views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :prenom, autofocus: true %>
 </div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :nom, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :adresse, autofocus: true %>
</div>  

<div class="field">
  <%= f.number_field :cp, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Ex: votre@mail.com" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <% if @validatable %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "8 caractères minimum" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.check_box :admin %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
```

I know I shouldn't give an admin field in my form but this is just for testing purposes. 
So when I check the checkbox and submit this form, it returns false.
I have no idea why. Any help, explanations, is much appreciated.

My **user_controller** if needed :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # Fais appel à la méthode permettant de restreindre l'accès uniquement aux admins
  # before_filter :authorize_admin, only: :index

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

 # GET /users/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /users
 # POST /users.json
 def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @user.save
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /users/1
# PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /users/1
# DELETE /users/1.json
def destroy
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.fetch(:user, {})
end
end
```

Comment: Could you post the params and also the checkbox elements when checked.
 e.g.
    <input name="post[validated]" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="post_validated" name="post[validated]" value="1" />

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you were asking for (sorry for being a boring noob :D) <label for="user_admin"><input name="user[admin]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[admin]" id="user_admin" /> Admin</label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key bit is right at the end:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.fetch(:user, {})
end
```

The whitelist (second argument) is empty so all the parameters are ignored. If you looked at your log file you would see a warning about parameters being ignored (you can configure this to raise an exception).

It isn't clear if the controller being used is your UsersController or devise's registration controller - you've show the view for one but the controller code for the other.

If you are using devise's registration controller, then `UsersController` may not be relevant - you would normally use a before filter to run something like this

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:admin, ...])
```

to change devise's default list of permitted fields.

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys and thanks for your answers ! Looks like I actually mispelled every single parmeters in my params....

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the place in your code where you make use of the `:admin` checkbox value, but I'm guessing that perhaps you simply ask if that param is `true` or not, like so?

```
if params[:user][:admin] == true
  do this...
else
  do this...
end
```

The problem with this is that the submitted checkbox value is, by default, a `"1"` if checked (note that it is of type `string`). A text string of any value is not equal to the boolean value of `true` or `false`.

You could update your code to something like:

```
if params[:user][:admin] == "1"
  do this...
else
  do this...
end
```

Rails always receives submitted params as `string` values